# Возможно ли сделать веревку на SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

вот то, что делаю http://codepen.io/cache0/pen/rjQwZJ

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="500">

    <path stroke="white" fill="none" id="bezier-path" stroke-width="1.2" d="M500,500 C500,224 500,151 500,0 " stroke-dasharray="4 2"/>

</svg>
```

надо к нижнему краю штриховой вертикальной линии
привязать конец "веревки"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
возможно ли сделать такую веревку на SVG и "привязать" её нужным концом к двигающейся точке так, чтобы длинна веревки сохранялась

Comment: "собсна" :)  SVG не поддерживает функцию drag and drop. А веревку можно нарисовать, легко и даже аннимировать её.

Answer (score 1):

ну в общем так: просто рисуется линия изогнутая, в атрибуте
d="M800.0,145.18H90.5c-2.91,0-90,0-90-68.32C.5,0,92.5.5,92.5.5H800.0"
M - длинна нижнего конца,
H - длинна верхнего конца
через javascript всё меняем

```
linia.setAttribute("d", "M"+(curX+500).toFixed(0)+",500 C500,224 500,151 500,0 ");
linia2.setAttribute("d", "M"+(750-((curX+500).toFixed(0)))+",145.18H90.5c-2.91,0-90,0-90-68.32C.5,0,92.5.5,92.5.5H"+(curX+500).toFixed(0));
```

и все! всем спасибо, все свободны